# Angular Dynamic Form does not update as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am having a generic form component called xform

**xform.component.html**

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="src && src.cols">
    <div fxLayout="row" *ngFor="let r of src.data|jag:src">
        <div fxFlex *ngFor="let c of r">
            <el [src]="c"></el>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

**XformComponent.ts**

```
export class XformComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() src: any;
}
```

**Here is my Jag pipe :**

```
export class JagPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any[], src: any): any {
    if (!data || !src) return [];
    if (!src.cols) src.cols = 2;
    var matrix = [], i, k;
    var els = data.filter(x => !x.hide);
    for (i = 0, k = -1; i < els.length; i++) {
      if (i % src.cols === 0) {
        k++;
        matrix[k] = [];
      }
      matrix[k].push(src.data[i]);
    }
    return matrix;
  }
}
```

**el.component.html**

```
<div fxLayout="row" *ngIf="src">
    <div fxFlex="100" [ngSwitch]="src.type">
        <mat-form-field> 
            <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="eltype.select">
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="src.value">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let x of src.obs | async" [value]="x.value">
                        {{x.text}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </ng-template>
                <!-- other controls like datepicker,autocomplete etc -->            
            <input matInput placeholder="{{src.title}}" *ngSwitchDefault [(ngModel)]="src.value">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ElComponent.ts**

```
export class ElComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() src:any;
  eltype=eltype;
}
```

I want to use my xform like below.

```
<xform [src]="arrayData">
```

I am expecting it to update `UI/form` for any change in my model .

It works and displays the form on the first load . But if I change hide flag or remove an item from array UI does not update as expected .

I tried `pure:false` for the pipe , but it goes infinite loop . I also tried calling a function in `ngFor` and it goes infinite loop .

Comment: i think it will be more easy to help if you will post the demo of the problem on stackblitz.com

Comment: Do you know stackblitz?